# Sort List by Number

Tags: java, list, sorting

My input -

```
List<String> parameterNames => [value0, type1, type0, name1, value1, name0]
```

I use Collections.Sort

```
Collections.sort(parameterNames)
```

I get the answer like this

```
[name0, name1, type0, type1, value0, value1]
```

I want to sort and get the list like this

```
[name0,type0,value0,name1,type1,value1]
```

will I be able to do this in Java??

Comment: Yes, you'll be able to do that in Java.

Comment: You can look into this http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/17/sorting-user-defined-objects-part-2/

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11257531/java-sort-algorithm-string-with-number

Answer (score 8):

Write a custom [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and pass it's instance to the `sort` method:

```
Comparator<String> myComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    public int compare(String str1, String str2) {
        // get the number at the end, and compare on the basis of that number
        // And then do the string comparison on substring before number
    }
};

Collections.sort(parameterNames, myComparator);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use [Collections.sort()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29), you can pass a [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to implement a custom method for checking what's higher and what's lower in search order.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use custom `Comparator` interface. If you faced problem to use `Comparator` than try to use following code:

```
    List<String> revList= new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> parameterNames=..//[value0, type1, type0, name1, value1, name0]
    for (String string : parameterNames) {
        revList.add(new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());//reverse the word
    }
    Collections.sort(revList);// Sort reverse word.

    for (String string : revList) {
        System.out.println(new StringBuilder(string).reverse().toString());
        // Again reverse to get desired output.
    }
```

**Output:**   name0,type0,value0,name1,type1,value1

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement your own [Comparator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) with this logic.

Assuming all your values are of the format `stringNUMBER`, here's a shot at the implementation:

```
/**
 * Compares two {@link String}s of the format stringNUMBER. Assumption: There is a single numeric     part to the string,
 * always at the end.
 */
public class TrailingNumberComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        int cmp = o1.substring(getStrartNumberIndex(o1)).compareTo(o2.substring(getStrartNumberIndex(o2)));
        if (cmp != 0) {
            return cmp;
        }
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    }

    private static int getStrartNumberIndex(String s) {
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return s.length();
    }
}
```

You'll then be able to call `Collections.sort(parameterNames, new TrailingNumberComparator())`;